# num_buckets as a parameter in a tensorflow feature column

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

Currently Tensorflow documentation define a categorical vocabulary column this way:

```
vocabulary_feature_column =
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key="feature_name_from_input_fn",
    vocabulary_list=["kitchenware", "electronics", "sports"])
```

However this suppose that we input manually the vocabulary list.
In case of large dataset with many columns and many unique values I would like to automate the process this way:

```
for k in categorical_feature_names:
    vocabulary_feature_column =
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key="feature_name_from_input_fn",
        vocabulary_list=list_of_unique_values_in_the_column)
```

To do so I need to retrieve the parameter `list_of_unique_values_in_the_column`.
Is there anyway to do that with Tensorflow?

I know there is tf.unique that could return unique values in a tensor but I don't get how I could feed the column to it so it returns the right vocabulary list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `list_of_unique_values_in_the_column` is known, you can save them in one file and read by  [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file). If unknown, you can use  [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_hash_bucket)  with a large enough size.